# How do I get these choices to render on my react form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, django-models

I am trying to get the options under APPRAISAL_TYPE to show up as options on my react form

```
class Appraisal(BaseModel):
    class APPRAISAL_TYPE(models.IntegerChoices):
        self_appraisal = 1
        line_manager = 2
        coo = 3
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=APPRAISAL_TYPE.choices, default=APPRAISAL_TYPE.self_appraisal)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    appraisal_for = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="re_appraisal_for")
    appraised_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

```
<InputGroup>
              <InputLeftAddon children="Category" borderRadius="16px" />
              <Select
                name="category"
                value={APPRAISAL_TYPE[appraisalDetails.status]}
                options={categoryOptions}
                onChange={(option) => handleChange(option, "category")}
              />
            </InputGroup>
```

However, since category, which is what APPRAISAL_TYPE is supposed to connect to, is an integer field, I get an error saying that an integer is expected.

Comment: Can you show the  object structure and what type of Select componet you are using

Comment: Hello, utter beginner here. What do you mean by object structure?

Comment: something like this "foo" : {
  "bar" : "Hello"
}, [read more here](https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json) and include some more relevant code, so we can understand the problem better

Comment: Like This?
const APPRAISAL_TYPE = {
    SelfAppraisal: { label: "Self-Appraisal", value: "1" },
    LineManager: { label: "Line Manager", value: "2" },
    Coo: { label: "COO", value: "3" },
  };

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// can use useMemo if this is expensive
let categoryOptions = Object.entries(APPRAISAL_TYPE).map(([key, value]) => {
  //console.log("item", key, value);
  // modify the props to suit the options needed by the component
  return {
    label: value.label,
    value: parseInt(value.value)
  };
});

// React JSX
 <InputGroup>
      <InputLeftAddon children="Category" borderRadius="16px" />
      <Select
          name="category"
          value={APPRAISAL_TYPE[appraisalDetails.status]}
          options={categoryOptions}
          onChange={(option) => handleChange(option, "category")}
       />
 </InputGroup>
```

What kind of `Select` component is being used, categoryOptions properites need to be change accordingly

Hope it helps you to sort out the problem.

Comment: Got this error: Field 'category' expected a number but got {'label': 'Self-Appraisal', 'value': '1'}.